# I want to publish add-on on google workspace marketplace But i was rejected for the following reasons - Menu options not shown after App is installed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, add-on, google-developers-console

I want to publish add-on on google workspace marketplace But I was rejected for the following reasons:

Menu - Menu options not shown after App is installed. Please ensure that the add-on correctly uses onInstall() and onOpen() to populate its menu.

Here's some code of my Code.gs file

```
function onInstall(e){
  onOpen(e);
}

function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
 .addItem("Open Connector", "openMethodPage")
 .addItem("Authorize", "launchAuthorizationDialog")
 .addItem("DisConnect", "deleteUserProperties")
 .addToUi();
 }
```

and here appscript.json

```
{
 "timeZone": "Asia/Seoul",
 "dependencies": {},
 "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
 "runtimeVersion": "V8",
 "oauthScopes": [
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
  ]
}
```

I look forward to your help. Thank you.

Comment: The event object for onInstall is not the same as the event object for onOpen() try using a separate function to build menu

Comment: There aren't enough details. Please add a [mcve]. Are there any message in the execution logs?

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for your reply.
I submitted the app again referring to your answer and I am waiting for your answer.

Comment: @Rubén Thank you for your reply.
I checked the execution logs and resubmitted the app and am currently waiting for the results.